# Shopify noob: In the documentation, why is JSON shown?

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to write a shopify store, and I noticed in the documentation (ex: http://docs.shopify.com/api/product_variant#show ) there's a lot of examples with JSON. When would I need JSON? It looks like all I need to know is Liquid to style everything. I don't see where JSON would be applicable. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That link with the JSON examples is for the Shopify API, which you would use if you wanted to make a [Shopify app](http://apps.shopify.com). You do not need the Shopify API if you just want to create a store and edit its theme (this is where you use Liquid).

[Shopify API docs](http://docs.shopify.com/api):

> Are you a developer looking to create a Shopify App?
>
> The Shopify API allows for an almost unlimited set of possibilities for interfacing the Shopify platform with your favorite CMS, web app, or other third party software.

[Shopify theme docs](http://docs.shopify.com/themes):

> Are you a web designer with a vision for a Shopify store?
>
> Learn what it takes to create a Shopify theme and make your vision a reality.
> From understanding our simple templating language "Liquid," to creating your first theme...